# Column value could come from 1 of 3 tables (not normalized)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need a query to populate a report. Most of the data will come from mainly one table (payment_history) but one of columns (Payee Name) will come for one of three tables (they're **almost** identical, the third table has more columns and the key column is named differently). The only thing I've tried is left outer join but all that does is add more columns. I need one column populated by three different tables

Example (in this example the value is in the bank_payees table:

Pseudo

```
select payment_history.Date, payment_history.Amount, payees_table_query.PayeeName, payees_table_query.PayeeId
from payment_history
```

Table **payment_history**

| Date | Amount | PayeeeInstance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/20/2019 | 150.21 | 1ef55 |
| 4/1/2020 | 1175.00 | A0z1l |

Table **user_payee_instance**

| PayeeInstance | PayeeId |
| --- | --- |
| 1ef55 | 1234 |
| A0z1l | 00a14468 |

Table **userpayees**

| PayeeId | PayeeName |
| --- | --- |
| null | null |

Table **bank_payees**

| PayeeId | PayeeName |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | Walmart |

Table **global_payees**

| InternalPayeeId | PayeeName | IndustryCode | CustomerId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00a14468 | Chase Bank | 9933 | 1000111 |

**Result**

| Date | Amount | PayeeName | PayeeId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/20/2019 | 150.21 | Walmart | 1234 |
| 4/1/2020 | 1175.00 | Chase Bank | 00a14468 |

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404376/rendered-view-requires-blank-line-before-tables-but-preview-accepts-both for why your tables weren't formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `UNION ALL` the three payee tables, you can treat them as one table *(which they probably should be in the first place)*.

Then it's just joining the tables together.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  payment_history
LEFT JOIN
  user_payee_instance
    ON user_payee_instance.PayeeInstance = payment_history.PayeeInstance
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT PayeeId, PayeeName FROM userpayees
  UNION ALL
  SELECT PayeeId, PayeeName FROM bank_payees
  UNION ALL
  SELECT InternalPayeeId, PayeeName FROM global_payees
)
  AS payees
    ON payees.PayeeId = user_payee_instance.PayeeId
```

Comment: That third table doesn't have the same # of columns and the key column name is different. I get an error "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists"

Comment: @Aaron But that is not true, in your question all 3 tables have 2 columns, an int and a varchar

Comment: @Aaron - We can only solve what's in your question, so fix the ... question!

Comment: @GuidoG Right. I see the confusion. I did say at the top that all 3 were almost identical. Those are examples. The third table global_payee has more columns and the key column is named differently. I'll update the original question

Comment: @MatBailie I updated the original question

Comment: @Aaron - I updated the answer straight afterwards

Comment: Do the payee ID columns all contain separate unique values?  If - for example - you have id 1234 in userpayees, can you also have a 1234 in bank_payees?  Another problem you are going to have is the different data types for the id's - which is going to cause some issues when joining the tables.